# Permitting only business days in ui.datepicker

Tags: angularjs

I am using the angular bootstrap datepicker in my form.

I am trying to achieve the following in this datepicker:

1. The minimum date that a user can pick is the next business day
2. The default date should be the next business day
3. In the date field only display Monday, December 22, 2014
4. Restrict users from selecting a non-business day

A business day would be M-F

Those who are familiar with configuring this widget, kindly advice.

Plnkr:

```
http://plnkr.co/edit/jKdD6W4vwrh9IkEgq5TR
```

Options:

```
//Set default date to be the next business day
  $scope.forDate = moment().add(1, 'days');

  //minDate should also start from next business day
  $scope.minDate = $scope.minDate ? null : new moment()

  //What should be entered here ?
  $scope.disable = function(){

  }
```

Comment: So what is the problem, there is a configuration option called `date-disabled`, which is a function that returns `true` for disabled days. http://plnkr.co/edit/945GntcdOpPB3V6Mn2Id?p=preview

Comment: Have you tried looking in the documentation. The answer is there.

Comment: .. which is shown in the very example for angular-ui datepicker, in fact, in the link that you posted in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set starting day as monday using

```
$scope.dateOptions = {
    'year-format': "'yy'",
    'starting-day': 1
  };
```

and you can disable week days like

```
  // Disable weekend selection
  $scope.disabled = function(date, mode) {
    return ( mode === 'day' && ( date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6 ) );
  };

  <input type="text" datepicker-popup="dd-MMMM-yyyy" ng-model="dt" open="opened" min="minDate" max="'2015-06-22'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" name='theDate' ng-required="true" />
```

look at `date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)`

here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WuQ99y3E9XArsRF9L7jL?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to disable weekends only then you could do it like this:

```
$('yourSelector').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends // disable weekends
});
```

Comment: That functionality is for jQuery UI datepicker, not UI Bootstrap Datepicker.